# Oracle user disconnected without committing/rolling back, not longer can change database

Tags: oracle

A user logged into the Oracle database I'm working with logged out without committing or rolling back and now my database cannot be changed, it seems to be locked.

I tried

```
 rollback
```

but that didn't work.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is impossible to log out of an Oracle database without committing or rolling back.  It is possible that the client application crashed or was forcibly terminated and did not have a chance to log out leaving a session on the server that is holding some locks.  If that is the case, the DBA would need to kill that session.

If you are the DBA and you're not sure what session needs to be killed, you can run the following query to get information about the various sessions that are holding locks that are blocking other sessions

```
SELECT ses.sid, ses.serial#, ses.username, ses.program, ses.osuser, ses.machine
  FROM v$session ses,
       dba_blockers blk
 WHERE blk.holding_session = ses.sid
```

Once you've identified which session(s) to kill

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '<<sid>>, <<serial#>>'
```

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave for your answer. To clarify, if the session isn't explicitly terminated it will never terminate automatically?

Comment: @RussellSilva - It depends what you mean by "automatic".  If the client application crashes, you can enable dead connection detection (DCD) on the database server.  That will cause the database to periodically ping the client to determine whether it is still up and to kill the session if the client has crashed.  That happens relatively quickly, though, so it wasn't related to the original question.  You can configure Oracle to kill sessions if they are idle too long.  In either of these cases, the session is explicitly terminated with a `rollback`, it's just terminated by the database.

Answer (score 3):

If the session did not rollback explicitly, if the database server can no longer reach a client its activity will be rolled back automatically, and then it will terminate the session.

The server is often quite happy if the client doesn't make a request to it for hours on end. See if you have SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME set to anything on the server. If it is a non-zero value, then that's how many minutes it will wait before checking to see if a client connection is dead. If it is zero, it won't check and will only be aware if it finds the client is dead when responding to a client request.

Also, the rollback may take some time. If a lot of work as been done, it may take hours. Anything waiting on that session will continue waiting until that rollback is complete