# What happens to my JDBC transaction if I lose my session

Tags: java, oracle, session, jdbc, transactions

I'm connecting to Oracle from a Java program, and doing the following:

- Start session
- Start transaction
- Insert a bunch of rows, call stored procedures, etc.
- Commit transaction
- End session

So . . . what happens if I lose my session (due to network problems or somewhat) in the middle of the transaction?  Do I get an automatic rollback?  Do I get rollback when transaction times out?  I am worried that my DB is going to be in an inconsistent state until Oracle gets around to cleaning up.

Comment: I'm worried about rows being locked for the transaction, and not being released until Oracle notices that my session is gone and goes ahead and rolls back for me.  Note I'm far from certain, which is why I'm asking . . .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932437/oracle-user-disconnected-without-committing-rolling-back-not-longer-can-change

Comment: Related: [Oracle user disconnected without committing/rolling back, not longer can change database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932437/oracle-user-disconnected-without-committing-rolling-back-not-longer-can-change) and [JDBC transaction rollback failure on closed connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449974/jdbc-transaction-rollback-failure-on-closed-connection).

Answer (score 1):

If your session is lost during the execution of a transaction the Oracle Database will automatically rollback your changes. You can read more about [Statement level atomicity](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT1115) in the documentation. If you lose your transaction because of a network problem you usually get a `ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel` and your transaction has been rolled back on the database.

However, this is only true when your session is lost on the database server itself. Especially with distributed transactions (XA) your database transaction usually stays alive while your JDBC session is gone, so be aware of that when you have XA transactions.

Also watch out for auto-commit which is by default turned on in the JDBC driver. This automatically commits every operation that you perform so if you have a longer going transaction with say 10 inserts and your 9th inserts fails, insert 1 - 8 have automatically been committed and won't be rolled back anymore. Auto-commit can be turned off via `Connection.setAutoCommit(false);`, see [setAutoCommit in the JDBC API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29)

Comment: Good point about auto-commit. Note that if you use an ORM that implements JPA (Java Persistence API), such as Hibernate or EclipseLink, auto-commit will be turned off automatically, overriding the default set by JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other replies which are all relevant I would like to add that if you lose the connection to the database in the middle of a commit you will receive an exception which doesn't tell you whether the commit was successful or not. To know whether the transaction was committed or not you can rely on Transaction Guard which is a new feature in 12c.

There is a blog that explains how it works:
https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/write_recovery_code_with_transaction

You can also refer to the Database Development Guide which has a section that describes Transaction Guard.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if I lose my session (due to network problems or
>   somewhat) in the middle of the transaction?

Exactly what happens depends on the database system (DBMS) you use, and its configuration. But most DBMS, in particular Oracle, have a timeout (or multiple timeouts) configured. If that timeout expires, the transaction will be rolled back.

With Oracle in particular, a DBA can list the open sessions on an Oracle server, and can forcibly kill the sessions even before their timeout has expired. The result will be the same: Any pending transaction inside the terminated session will be rolled back.

> I am worried that my DB is going to be in an inconsistent state until Oracle gets around to cleaning up.

That depends on what you mean by "inconsistent state", and on the transaction isolation level you used. As long as the transaction is still open, there may be some side effects, such as:

- other seeing seeing partially changed data (that depends on the isolation level)
- rows/tables being locked

Once the transaction has rolled back, is is as if it never happened. That, after all, is the purpose of using transactions :-).
If you are worried that your transactions may hang around for too long, you will probably have to tune the relevant timeouts.